# How to scrape this PDF in Python?

Tags: python, pdf, screen-scraping

I want to scrape the information on this PDF in python.. I'm not sure where to start because it isn't organized at all. I'm used to scraping HTML. I tried converting it to HTML and that didn't really help.

How would you try to scrape this PDF? Here is a link to the PDFs (any will work, they're all similar): http://www.snco.us/doc/booking/(S(mgv3bhohvbweq0rj4wsq3puo))/inmate/DailyBookingArchive?Length=0

Thank you for any help :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would do it, and then just build from here as needed.

```
import PyPDF2 as p2
import xlsxwriter

pdfFileName = "NAME OF PDF HERE.pdf"
pdfFile = open(pdfFileName, 'rb')
pdfread = p2.PdfFileReader(pdfFile)


pageinfo = pdfread.getPage(0)
rawInfo = pageinfo.extractText().split('\n')

row = 0
column = 0

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Workbook_Name.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Sheet1')

for line in rawInfo:
    worksheet.write(row, column, line)
    row += 1
workbook.close()
```

Comment: Thank you. Is this creating a seperate file? What is the worksheet thing, I've never used it.

Comment: That is putting it into an excel document. Save the pdf file into the same folder your code is being ran from. change the pdfFileName to the name of the pdf document. Then what this does is opens the pdf, reads the first page, and splits all of the information up, then writes it into an excel document in column A 1 row at a time.  I forgot one part of this that is very important. You have to add workbook.close() at the end. See my edit.

Comment: That is what I thought, and I added that too at the end after I looked up about xlsxwriter.. but now I'm getting this error:xlsxwriter.exceptions.FileCreateError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'test2.xlsx' 

Edit: never mind had to run it as admin

Comment: @BrodySchuman Did you get it to work after running it as admin?  Let me know if I answered your question or if you need anything else.

Comment: It does work, but the thing is the PDF is missing some entrys on some sections. Like if you look at the PDF theres multiple lines for some bookings. So I'm not sure how to tell the script to decide which info goes with which person.

Comment: @BrodySchuman What are you trying to grab? Your original question asked how to read the document. That is reading the document the way it is build. Now if you are wanting to extract certain information you will have to write a series of if statements to look through each line and IF it falls under certain categories, write the info. But i don't know what info you are trying to pull. Names? Dates? What they were arrested for?

Comment: I want to grab each section, so I'm trying to organize it so each section gives me their name, booking number, sex, etc. Everything I can get from it.

Comment: You are basically asking someone to completely write an entire script for you. Post what you have so far and what you are trying to accomplish and we will be able to help fix the areas that need to be improved.